# Facebbook Hackbook ios app is not working

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First of all i have downloaded the Facebook app form app store and logged in there and then i downloaded the Hackbbok form this url https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk and installed into my phone through xcode.

When Hackbook application is launched it shows "Login with Facebook" button. When i click on that button it opens the facebook app which i downloaded form app store and then re launches Hackbook. But Hackbook still asks for login.

But when i uninstall facebook app which i downloaded from app store then it works fine as browser is launched when i click on the login button

Similarly i have another app which imports contacts from Facebook when i download facebook app from app store and login there then my app doesn't import contacts and shows blank screen and when i uninstall the facebbok app then it starts working again.

Both apps works fine if Facebook app is not installed.

Any help regarding to this issue will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you working off the IOS simulator or on an actual device? I have found that trying to install other apps on the simulator doesn't always work (depending on the app)... I'd you're experiencing this on the simulator, try on an actual device and see if you can reproduce the same issue, let me know your results...

Comment: I am trying on actual device one is 3gs with ios 4.1 and other 3gs with ios 5.1

Comment: @CocoaNoob Could you tell me how to install the Facebook app from the app store on the iOS Simulator?

Comment: No it is not possible to install app from app store on simulator. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137791/can-i-access-the-app-store-from-within-the-ios-simulator