# Run iOS Apps on Windows Server

Tags: ios, testing, emulation, simulator

We are selling an iOS app on the app store which requires an extremly complicated server-side setup.  The problem is that most of our customers have strict IT restrictions and they only allow us to connect to their servers via software (such as GoToAssist, LogMeIn, GoToMyPC, etc..).

The problem is that when support is configuring their server, they have absolutely no way to run the iOS app and test their configurations.  We need a way to download the iOS app onto a simulator on their Windows server and run the simulator from their internal network so we can open the app and test.

Ideally this would be all done from their Windows server.  However, if there is a way to do it from the Mac, that is acceptable too.  However, we cannot use the iOS simulator that comes with XCode because that will require us to put our source-code on the customers Mac in order to run the app.  We need a simulator that will download and run the app from the app-store.

Comment: You can copy a simulator build to another Mac without needing to have the source code on that Mac.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

1. You must have a Mac with Xcode to use an iOS simulator. However, there are some iOS emulators out there. For more info, check out this link:
   [iOS Emulators](https://www.androidstrike.com/best-ios-emulators-for-windows-run-ios-apps-on-pc/#What_is_an_iOS_Emulator)
2. iOS Simulators cannot run App Store apps. For more information on why, check out this link:
   [Can I access the App Store from within the iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137791/can-i-access-the-app-store-from-within-the-ios-simulator)